# Reading and writing unique XML tags in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I want to take a .txt file in XML of this sort:

```xml
<?xml version = ""?>
<data>
    <a1>cat</a1>
    <a5>bird</a5>
    <a4>window</a4>
</data>
```

count the length of each string and output:

```xml
<?xml version = ""?>
<result>
    <r1>3</r1>
    <r5>4</r5>
    <r4>6</r4>
</result>
```

What's the best way to write a .txt xml format file with the above output and corresponding tags? I'm using `xml.etree.cElementTree` to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
xdata = '''
<data>
    <a1>cat</a1>
    <a5>bird</a5>
    <a4>window</a4>
</data>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xdata)

for apptag in root.findall("*"):
    apptag.text = str(len(apptag.text))
    apptag.tag = re.sub(r'^a(.*)',r'r\1',apptag.tag)
root.tag = 'result'
ET.ElementTree(root).write('test.xhtml')
```